# Deploying web service application using Docker

Tags: docker, google-compute-engine

I'm using Docker to deploy my web service to GCE and I'm following the instructions given here: https://blog.golang.org/docker

I have created a private repository on Bitbucket, made an automated build and I'm able to run my build with "docker run namespace/repo" remembering to run "docker login" beforehand (!).

Now, creating the GCE instance succeeds without errors, but my image is not running (using "sudo docker ps")

How can I setup the containers.yaml to install private Docker images?

Below is my containers.yaml file:

```yaml
version: v1beta2
containers:
- name: my-webservice
  image: namespace/repo:latest
  ports:
  - name: http
    hostPort: 80
    containerPort: 8080
```

Comment: Logging in to the server afterwards and pull/run the image is of course a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't see anything in the manifest that would let you specify the login credentials in the [manifest spec](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/container_vms#container_manifest), but there might be a way to workaround it.

You can run startup scripts, so try to create one with

```
#!/bin/sh
docker login -u your_user -p yourpassword
```

Then add the startup script to your instance with

```
gcloud compute instances add-metadata yourvmname \
--metadata-from-file startup-script=yourshellscript.sh
```

That should run that script before docker starts and have you logged in when it pulls the images.

If that doesn't work, there is a method to load docker images from your cloud storage bucket called docker-registry-driver-gcs. You can see the example [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/container_vms#example_manifest_file).